# How to fetch process,thread name,levelname in customized python logger

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, wxpython, ironpython

I am developing customized logger program,as per the requirement i need to fetch the process,thread and name of object Inside the called function(In below example its obj needs to fetch inside the get_configured_logger function) and class name to which obj belongs. as shown with comments in below code,  please give some ideas to achieve this.

```
import logging, logging.handlers
from logging import StreamHandler, Formatter
class A:
  def get_configured_logger(self,name):
      logger = logging.getLogger(name)
      if (len(logger.handlers) == 0):                
                FORMAT = "%(process)s %(thread)s:-(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)-%(module)"

                #print 'process:',process
                #print 'thread:',thread
                #print 'levelname:',levelname
                #print  'Module:',(name portion of filename).

                #print 'obj:,'name of the object(Eg:obj),current function( Eg: get_configured_logger) called by' 
                #print 'class name:(obj is instance of class)' 
                formatter = logging.Formatter(fmt=FORMAT)                                 
                handler = logging.StreamHandler()
                handler.setFormatter(formatter)
                logger.addHandler(handler)
                logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)        
      return logger

if __name__=="__main__":
    obj=A()
    logger = obj.get_configured_logger("DEMO")
    logger.debug("TEST")
```

Thanks

hema

Answer (score 42):

To add current process/thread name to a log message you could specify in the format string:

```
%(processName)s %(threadName)s
```

To get them as strings:

```
process_name = multiprocessing.current_process().name
thread_name = threading.current_thread().name
```

Comment: Just for completeness I would like to add the `ident` attribute, for getting the thread's identifier. For the current process I usually use `os.getpid()`

Answer (score 7):

### Thread name

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.current_thread) describes an easy interface to access the current `Thread`, you can then use its [`name`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.name) attribute to have the Thread name.

You can then use:

```
import threading
threading.current_thread().name
```

Be aware that it's not unique.

### Process name

There is no easy way of getting the process name as this is dependent on the OS you are using. You can however get the process ID (`pid`) doing:

```
import os
os.getpid()
```

That is unless you are using the `multiprocessing` module and launch subprocesses, in which case you can use the `multiprocessing` module which presents an interface closely similar to that of the `Threading` module.